# EF Core migration creates incorrect enums

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, migration, npgsql

What can be the reason that EF Core can incorrectly read db context and set wrong enum types for database?

I had **DB-First** and scaffolded context and entities in my project.
After it was found out there are unmapped enums in my db and my context, I created enums in Pascal case and mapped them to tables like this:

```
modelBuilder
    .HasPostgresEnum<AutoStatus>()
    .HasPostgresEnum<AnotherEnum>()
    .HasPostgresEnum<AndAnotherEnum>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Auto>(entity =>
    entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("status")
        .HasConversion<string>()
        .HasDefaultValueSql(AutoStatus.InAssembly.ToString())
        .HasColumnType(nameof(AutoStatus));
);
```

Next was created an "Initial" migration and I tried to update (create) database by this migration. But EF spat out error **"42704: type "autostatus" does not exist"**.

So, migration, migration designer and model snapshot had *another* enums for some reason:

- Migration:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
    .Annotation("Npgsql:Enum:auto_status", "in_assembly,ready_to_test,in_test,ready_to_sale,sold")
```

- Migration Designer:

```
NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions.HasPostgresEnum(modelBuilder, "auto_status", new[] { "in_assembly", "ready_to_test", "in_test", "ready_to_sale", "sold" });
```

- Context Snapshot
  `NpgsqlModelBuilderExtensions.HasPostgresEnum(modelBuilder, "auto_status", new[] { "in_assembly", "ready_to_test", "in_test", "ready_to_sale", "sold" });`

Why still there are old enums, if nowhere in project aren't uses of old (snakecase) enums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to call MapEnum onto NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
dataSourceBuilder.MapEnum<AutoStatus>("auto_status");
var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AutoDealerContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(dataSource));
```

Enum:

```
public enum AutoStatus
{
    InAssembly,
    ReadyToTest,
    InTest,
    ReadyToSale
    Sold
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<AutoStatus>();
}
```

It is also important to note, that call `.HasConversion<string>()` unecessary:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Auto>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Status)
        .HasColumnName("status")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("'in_assembly'");
}
```